# Async Message Queue - which combination?

Tags: python, messaging, mongrel, tornado, zeromq

I have been trying to determine which combination of packages to use for a push messaging service behind a web site...
My current idea is to go with Tornado + Socket.IO (Tornadio) and ZMQ. But I was also looking at involving Mongrel2. Then there is also a similar project called Brubeck, that takes from Tornado, using ZMQ and Eventlet.
My main question is this... I'm trying to understand where the benefit of Mongrel2 would come into play if I were to use Tornado. At that point, is Tornado even necessary? I figured at that point I would just be writing a Mongrel2 python handler and thats it. I would like to focus on using websockets/jssockets which is why using Socket.IO was interesting since it handles all the backwards compatibility under the hood for you.

If the tools in the mix for consideration are: Python focus, Tornado, Mongrel2, ZMQ, Brubeck, and Socket.IO, what recommendations would you have for the best mix to support websockets? Having Mongrel2 was really appealing for the idea of scalability, and just turning on more python handlers.

## Update 1/1/2012

At first went with Tornado + TornadIO + ZeroMQ, and had a working server. But ultimately I ended up learning Go ([www.golang.org](http://www.golang.org)) and rewrote my server using pure Go with its built in concurrency. Ended up being faster than python by over 10x even with more features than my Python version: http://www.justinfx.com/2011/07/28/go-language-for-python-programmers/

It seems to keep on picking up speed as the Go team makes more releases towards Go 1.0

Comment: What's the problem with a standard message queue like RabbitMQ - working since ages and rocket solid.

Comment: I have used ZMQ before, for a python RPC module between apps. I really liked it and want to stick with it. Its also the core of Mongrel2 and has a lot of support in Tornado as well.

Comment: You are asking for suggestion on which tools to choose, but you need to explain a bit (and generalize) the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: For the website, we want a bidirectional connection so that a user can subscribe to multiple message channels at once. And be able to post messages to channels. So whether they are on a one-on-one chat with another user...or receiving real-time messages related to the current forum they are on. We wanted to focus on websockets as opposed to long polling.  Basically just the ability for pub-sub, with arbitrary amounts of sub channels. I figured with their socket connection they could specify the channels they want, and a sub could be started for them in the server handler.

Comment: I'm using tornado+socketio(tornadio)+redis(via brukva) for pub/sub.

Comment: @Mike - What was your reasoning to go with redis over zeromq? It looks very interesting.

Comment: @Justin: redis was even easier to install and it can be used not only for pub/sub but as fast data storage as well. Python bindings for zeromq provides copy-pasted tornado IOLoop implementation and this also complicates the system (what if tornado will change the IOLoop?), brukva uses standard IOLoop. I think there are valid reasons for this decision but redis just was easier and it works well. The idea behind zeromq is very nice and I think I'll eventually use it in one of the future projects.

Comment: I suppose the only remaining question is what the performance of Redis pub/sub is in comparison to zeromq. I cant seem to find any real data on it. But what I did find suggests that Redis probably caps at about 100k messages per second, whereas ZeroMQ claims its about 1 million+. It was suggested that Redis is perfect as long as the implementation does not have a goal of being absolutely realtime. So it might work great for a chat room, but maybe not so great for pushing tons of event stuff at a high rate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am adding my own update to this question as the answer, since I never received any other answers, and so I can close this one down...

At first went with Tornado + TornadIO + ZeroMQ, and had a working server. But ultimately I ended up learning Go (www.golang.org) and rewrote my server using pure Go with its built in concurrency. Ended up being faster than python by over 10x even with more features than my Python version: http://www.justinfx.com/2011/07/28/go-language-for-python-programmers/

It seems to keep on picking up speed as the Go team makes more releases towards Go 1.0

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a job for the Flash/Javascript binding. http://www.zeromq.org/bindings:javascript

That way you have a ZMQ app in the browser that is a SUB to whatever PUB sockets are pushing relevant messages.

Comment: Actually I was asking about the server implementation, not the client-side. Also, I don't want to rely on flash. My goal was to stick with python applications.

Comment: If you want to run in the browser, then you can't use Python. Also, the javascript binding just uses a flash object to get to real sockets. ZMQ is pretty agnostic so it is easy to use Python on the server and other stuff on the client. But build your client prototype in Python first.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but I think this isn't really addressing my question. I am not concerned about the client at all. What I was trying to find out was peoples opinions on server-side combinations for developing a message queue. I ended up writing my server with Tornado + TornadIO + ZMQ. So far its working. But now I am wondering about switching to Redis for the persistance. Im still torn on whether Mongrel2 would have been a better base or not.  The client aspect is all javascript via socket.io